# trigger conflict error ,name entered more than once,PSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm working with this database ... basically I have to create a "promotion_cyclist" trigger, to store the eligible athletes (who finished first in a stage of the Giro d'Italia) in the mesh table. The trigger basically works, but it can happen that if a cyclist has won more than one stage, the name of this will be inserted several times in 'Magliarosa'. I would like it to be inserted only once ... so next to the name in 'magliarosa' i put 'UNIQUE' ... the problem is that now I am back with a conflict error ... can you help me?

The tables are:

- cyclist (cyclist_id: Int, name_cyclist: string, team: string of three letters, country: three-letter string)
- tape (_name: string, km: int, type: 'flat' or 'high_mountain' or 'medium_mountain' or 'chronometro_a_team' or 'chronometro_individual' or 'time_trial')
- arrival_order (cyclist_id: int; tape_name: string, order: int): where cyclist_id (resp, tape_name) is a foreign key that refers to cyclist (resp, tape);
- Magliarosa (name: string);

this is the trigger I load on the shell ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION promote_cyclist()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO magliarosa
        SELECT c.name_cyclist
        FROM cyclist c
        WHERE new.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id AND
              new.order = 1;
RETURN NEW;
END ;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is the command I pass to the shell:

```
CREATE TRIGGER promuovi_ciclista
    BEFORE INSERT ON ordine_arrivo
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE promuovi_ciclista();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, maybe change the trigger to this :

```
INSERT INTO magliarosa
    SELECT c.name_cyclist
    FROM cyclist c
    WHERE new.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id 
    AND new.order = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM magliarosa 
         WHERE magliarosa.name_cyclist = c.name_cyclist -- or better to save cyclist_id and compare the id
         )
```

Comment: hmm.. It should unless `magliarosa.name_cyclist = c.name_cyclist` is not the right join there

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
INSERT INTO magliarosa
        SELECT c.name_cyclist
        FROM cyclist c
        WHERE new.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id AND
              new.order = 1
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

in the trigger to catch and ignore the constraint violation.

Comment: i tried to add
'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' before the return in the trigger but it doesn't work ... what am I wrong?

Comment: syntax error at or at "ON"
ROW 10: ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Comment: You have to write it correctly. Answer expanded.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it like this ...where is the error?

```
CREATE FUNCTION promote_cyclist()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO magliarosa
        SELECT c.name_cyclist
        FROM cyclist c
        WHERE new.cyclist_id = c.cyclist_id AND
              new.order = 1;
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
RETURN NEW;
END ;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```